# Receiving error 'Can't find variable:require' when using Chutzpah/PhantomJS in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, requirejs, chutzpah, jasmine2.0

First: I have looked at a number of tickets that address similar issues, but I feel that mine is different is a particular respect: I have just installed the Chutzpah test runner in Visual Studio 2015, and I don't know what to expect from that test runner in terms of PhantomJS and RequireJS. I don't know what is already configured for me within the plugin, and what I need to configure myself.

I have just begun to use the Chutzpah test runner within Visual Studio 2015.

I am writing tests within the Jasmine framework.

Here is my current chutzpah.json configuration:

[image]

I have successfully run some throwaway Jasmine tests that do not leverage any additional libraries:

[image: throw away jasmine test]

[image: throwaway test results]

It was my understanding that the Chutzpah test runner makes use of PhantomJS, so I attempted to write a test to verify that PhantomJS is available.

I copied the first line of the tutorial on the PhantomJS landing page:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
```

I interpolated this into the following unit test:

```
describe('PhantomJS', function () {
    it('can create a web page', function () {
        var page = require('webpage').create();
        expect(page).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

After running this test, I receive the following error:

```
Message:ReferenceError:Can't find variable:require in ... {pointer to test file}
```

My understanding is that Chutzpah already makes use of RequireJS.

My question is:

Should I expect PhantomJS and RequireJS to be natively supported by the Chutzpah test runner in Visual Studio 2015, or do I need to add and configure additional modules?

Thank you for your attention. Clarifying questions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chutzpah uses PhantomJS but you can't directly access its built in require function. If you want to invoke a phantom webpage level api you can use the following code:

```
window.callPhantom(
{
  Type:"Eval",
  Data: "phantom.pagesize(100,200);"
});
```

As for RequireJS, Chutzpah supports working with it but does not come bundled with it. You must reference it yourself. Please [check out the samples](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/tree/master/Samples/RequireJS) in the Chutzpah repo. These can help you get started.